# re-linking linked list? Chess game

Tags: java

There's a portion of my chess game that isn't working right. To make the explanation simple, I wont give all the details besides ones that matter. I have a chessboard stored as a linked list of chess pieces. The program is supposed to read a line of integers like "2 2 4 4".

This example line would move the piece from spot 2, 2 to spot 4, 4.

If a piece is at 4, 4 and a different color than the moving piece, the piece at 4, 4 would get deleted and the piece's coordinates at 2, 2 would be changed to 4, 4.

I think I'm not re-linking the list properly after deleting the link holding the piece that needs to be deleted. Code below that matters.

```
for (int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3; a < token2.length && b < token2.length && c < token2.length
                && d < token2.length; a += 4, b += 4, c += 4, d += 4) {
            //reads integers to determine which piece to move and where.

            int MoveFromCol = Integer.parseInt(token2[a]);
            int MoveFromRow = Integer.parseInt(token2[b]);
            int MoveToCol = Integer.parseInt(token2[c]);
            int MoveToRow = Integer.parseInt(token2[d]);

            //finds the chesspiece object that is moving.
            chessPiece MovingPiece = theBoard.findMovingPiece(MoveFromCol, MoveFromRow);
            //stores the piece type (rook, queen, etc).
            String SpacePieceType = theBoard.CheckPieceAtSpot(MoveToCol, MoveToRow);

            //if there isn't another piece at the spot we're moving to, just change the moving piece's coordinates
            //to the new spot if the piece could move.
            if (SpacePieceType.equals("no piece") && MovingPiece.canMove(theBoard, MoveToCol, MoveToRow, SpacePieceType)) {
                theBoard.updateLink(MoveFromCol, MoveFromRow, MoveToCol, MoveToRow);
            }
            //If there was a piece at spot we're moving to, different color, and we can move there, delete that piece 
            //and change moving pieces coordinates to new spot. 
            if (MovingPiece.canMove(theBoard, MoveToCol, MoveToRow, SpacePieceType) && !SpacePieceType.equals("no space")) {

                theBoard.delete(MoveToCol, MoveToRow);
                theBoard.updateLink(MoveFromCol, MoveFromRow, MoveToCol, MoveToRow);

            }
        }
```

In class containing list methods

```
  public Link delete(int Col, int Row) {

    Link current = head;
    Link previous = head;

    while (current.piece.col != Col && current.piece.row != Row) {

        if (current.next == null) {
            return null;
        } else {

            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    if (current == head) {

        head = head.next;
    } else {

        previous.next = current.next;
    }

    return current;
}


  public void updateLink(int oldCol, int oldRow, int newCol, int newRow) {

    Link current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        if (oldCol == current.piece.col && oldRow == current.piece.row) {

            current.piece.col = newCol;
            current.piece.row = newRow;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Test your linked list separately from your game.  Verify that you can add, delete elements in different circumstances.  For example, add 3 elements, delete 3 elements, and verify that you can still add more elements.  Print the list after each modification.

Comment: Also, assuming you want the ability to delete nodes in your linked list at specific positions, make sure you can delete nodes at the start of of the list, the second item, the last item, and the second-from-last item.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to completely separate the linked list code from the logic of your game.  The linked list should implemented with the interface of an abstract data type with well-defined operations such as add, remove, and a toString method to print its contents.

Comment: Okay, I added these pieces with the locations (1, 1), (6, 1), and (6, 6). I'm calling my delete method for 1, 1 and 6, 1. But when I print the list, it's showing me only the piece at 1, 1 (which should have been deleted). Which means something's wrong. :(

Comment: With linked list code, it's best to have a pen and paper handy and to walk through your code and update your drawings of the nodes and pointers as you "execute" each line of your code by hand.  Linked lists can be quite tricky.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Java implementation of LinkedLists (assuming this is some sort of assignment)?

Comment: No, we had to build or own

Comment: In your delete node code, make sure you are actually finding the node to be deleted.  There may be an issue with the logical condition in your `while`.

Comment: Change your while loop condition to "`while (current.piece.col != Col || current.piece.row != Row)`" instead of "`while (current.piece.col != Col && current.piece.row != Row)`".  Remember that the `NOT (A AND B)` is equivalent to `NOT(A) OR NOT(B)` (one of DeMorgan's Laws).

Comment: How would that change up the result? With the &&, wouldn't it cycle through the list until a link was found that matched the desired deletion?

Comment: With your current condition, you get out of the while loop too early and delete a node that does not match your search criteria.  For example, try deleting a node in the middle or end of your list and print your list after the deletion.  My guess is that a node earlier than the node you chose will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a problem.  Let's say that you have a list that looks like this [(4,7),(3,3),(2,3),(1,1)] where (4.7) is at the head of the list.  Now call delete so that you delete (1,1), then (2,3), then (3,3), then (4,7). Your second delete (2,3) will delete (3,3) instead.  Your third delete (3,3) will delete (2,3) even though (3,3) doesn't even exist in the list.  Your fourth delete (4,7) will delete the correct item.  If you change the logic as I suggested, you will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have other errors, but your delete routine is definitely incorrect.  Fixing the logical condition in your while loop fixes this error.  As an aside, you don't need to fix the similar-looking condition in your `updateLink` method, because it's not a negated conjunction, and therefore, not subject to [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

```
public Link delete(int Col, int Row) {

    Link current = head;
    Link previous = head;

    while (current.piece.col != Col || current.piece.row != Row) {

        if (current.next == null) {
            return null;
        } else {

            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    if (current == head) {

        head = head.next;
    } else {

        previous.next = current.next;
    }

    return current;
}
```